# How do Apache Modules work in terms of memory consumption

Tags: c, apache, memory, apache-modules

I want to write a big Apache Module in C with many lines of code and many dependencies to external libraries and compile it with APXS. 
Lets assume that the code segment of this C program consumes a huge chunk of memory: 100 MB.

What happens concerning the memory, when the module is called 5 times concurrently?
Is the code segment of the C program shared between each invocation, similar to multi-threading, or is the code segment copied in memory?

If the answer is copy:
Since I'm working on a Linux machine, does the "Copy-on-Write" mechanism reliably prevent the actual copy in memory?

At the end: Does the code segment of the 5 concurrent calls consume 100 MB or 500 MB?

Comment: You need to install Apache on Linux, then poke around modules and create a sample one to start

Comment: Given the size and intensity you mention, I doubt the efficiency of such a module added to http latency ...